# Golang passing pointer to sql .Scan() returns pointers

Tags: go, pointers

Confused as to why the below is happening.
TLDR; I'm passing a pointer and a "&val" to database/sql 's **Scan** method, and getting different results

```
rows, err := db.Query(selectRowsQuery)
val = new(int)

for rows.Next() {
  err = rows.Scan(val)
...
fmt.Println(val)      // 0xc0000b6c48
```

Val's value is a pointer. Why does val stay as a pointer?

but if I do this:

```
var val int
...
err = rows.Scan(&val)
fmt.Println(val)          // 0
```

val returns as the value. Aren't **"&val"** (val is an int value) and **"val"** (val is a pointer to int) the same thing?

Comment: To print the integer instead of the pointer in the first snippet of code, dereference the pointer: `fmt.Println(*val)`

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go for language fundamentals or consult any C reference on what pointers are and how they behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, when you do `val = new(int)` you are getting a pointer, and `rows.Scan(val)` is putting a value into the location that pointer is pointing to correctly, but you're printing `fmt.Println(val)`: which just means you want Go to print the pointer. Which it did... the string representation of a pointer is the address it's pointing to. What you'd want to do is `fmt.Println(*val)`, which says 'print the value that the pointer is pointing to'.

The second example works correctly because `var val int` initializes a value, and `fmt.Println(val)` prints it correctly. `err = rows.Scan(&val)` required you to send the address of `val` by calling `&val` because that's how we tell `rows.Scan` where to put the data instead of passing it data that it can't do anything with.

Comment: Thanks!! Very clear explanation, makes sense now :)